# Converting .ai files to .pdf and priting through .pdf but the colors don't match

Tags: color-conversion

I am converting a design made in illustrator CC to PDF, but when I printed it through PDF the colors are so different but when I look on the screen the  PDF file open it is fine.

I've read this earlier [Colour difference between Ai file print and PDF file print](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37138/colour-difference-between-ai-file-print-and-pdf-file-printand)

I've done it, but nothing changed.

Please help?

Thank you,

Comment: Hey Mila, welcome to Graphic Design Exchange. It would be great if you could add a bit of detail, so other users can understand your problem and come up with an answer. For example, these are a few details that would help me understand your problem: What is the original colour mode of your AI file, RGB or CMYK? What settings are you using when you export it to PDF? What colour profile are you using in your final PDF? What kind of printer are you using to print the PDF? What do you mean by "the colors are so different"? Good luck!

Comment: *"I printed it through PDF the colors are so different but when I look on the screen the PDF file open it is fine."* -- This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your illustrated document is in CMYK! If you are using any RGB colors they will appear differently when converted to PDF in default settings. You **can** have a PDF with RGB colors however all printers will print in CMYK. This is most likely the reason you are seeing a variation in color. Other things to consider might be; printer calibration, monitor calibration, the color profile used in the pdf etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**You might have to calibrate your screen.**
It's basically a process that makes sure the screen shows colors as they are printed.
I'd add a link to a calibration tutorial but the best is to look for one specific to your specific screen, and even better if you know which kind of printer you will be using, look for how to calibrate your specific screen to the specific printer